# Implicit value of objects

Tags: typescript

How do you allow TypeScript to implicitly type the value of a object if the key is defined?

```
type SupportedTypes = 'text' | 'currency' | 'date';

const toData : {[key in SupportedTypes] : (arg0: string) => string | number | Date} = {
    text: (str: string) : string => str,
    currency: (str: string) : number => Number(str),
    date: (str: string) : Date => new Date(str)
}

const _temp = () => {
    return toData.text('hello ') + toData.text('everyone')
}
```

The error I get from the return of `_temp` is:

```
TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'string | number | Date' and 'string | number | Date'.
```

I want to type to Date like this:

`{[key in SupportedTypes] : (arg0: string) => FIGURE_IT_OUT}`

but with the FIGURE_IT_OUT prompting TypeScript to derive the type from the functions within it :) I tried `(arg0: string) => any` but this actually defines it as any.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to explicitly type `toData` at all... maybe you're looking for [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1EeOw)? If that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

One general solution is use `satisifies` operator to keep type information not lost.

But it seems like the return type is mapped from the method so I suggest to defined a mapping, then use it to define the type for `toData`:

```
interface ToDataReturnMap {
  text: string,
  currency: number,
  date: Date
}

type ToData = {
  [K in keyof ToDataReturnMap]: (arg0: string) => ToDataReturnMap[K]
}

const toData : ToData = {
  text: str => str,
  currency: str => Number(str),
  date: str => new Date(str)
}
```